# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'iterateObject')

Tags: angular, autocomplete, ag-grid

I was trying to implement ag-grid autocomplete Editor from https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-autocomplete-editor?file=index.js

I was currently on ag-grid-community version 22.2.1 but this package required v 23.2.1 minimum. I verified the same by installing the dependencies on the stackBlitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-autocomplete-editor?file=index.js). After updating my ag-grid version, I'm seeing the following error and none of the grids are rendering on my app.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'iterateObject')
    at AgGridAngular.push../node_modules/ag-grid-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/dist/agGridAngular.js.AgGridAngular.checkForDeprecatedEvents (agGridAngular.js:423)
    at AgGridAngular.push../node_modules/ag-grid-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/dist/agGridAngular.js.AgGridAngular.ngAfterViewInit (agGridAngular.js:377)
    at callHook (core.js:4726)
    at callHooks (core.js:4690)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:4630)
    at refreshView (core.js:12129)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13499)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11770)
    at refreshView (core.js:12105)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:13445)
```

If someone can tell me how to get my ag-grids to render so that I can test the autocomplete editor, that would be great.